# Find records with start and end time when value doesn't increase for more than 1 minute in SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, datetime, apache-spark-sql

I am stuck with a problem on sql server, where I need to find start time if the value does not increase for more than 1 minute while the end time is when the value increases and my data looks like below

```
Name  Timestamp     Value
--------------------------
M1  2022-05-04T00:00:00 580
M1  2022-05-04T00:01:00 581
M1  2022-05-04T00:02:00 582
M1  2022-05-04T00:03:00 583
M1  2022-05-04T00:04:00 584
M1  2022-05-04T00:05:00 584
M1  2022-05-04T00:06:00 584
M1  2022-05-04T00:07:00 584
M1  2022-05-04T00:08:00 585
M1  2022-05-04T00:09:00 585
M1  2022-05-04T00:10:00 586
M1  2022-05-04T00:11:00 586
M1  2022-05-04T00:12:00 586
M1  2022-05-04T00:13:00 587
M1  2022-05-04T00:14:00 588
```

The result should look like

```
Start time             End time         Value
---------------------------------------------
2022-05-04T00:04:00 2022-05-04T00:07:00 584
2022-05-04T00:10:00 2022-05-04T00:12:00 586
```

I tried with queries like below but it is not working

```
    SELECT *
    FROM (SELECT *, lag(a.Value) OVER (partition by a.Name ORDER by timestamp) pr
    FROM table a
    ORDER BY timestamp) a
    WHERE a.Value = a.pr
```

Please Help!

Comment: "it is not working" is one of the least helpful ways of describing your problem. What is happening?

Comment: This looks like a simple min and max grouped by value having count > 1

Comment: [Stack Overflow Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/)

Comment: @CHill60 apologies if the problem statement is not clear. the problem states that machine M1 starts when its Value doesn't increase for > 1 minute and stops when M1 value increases.

Comment: @P.Salmon thanks for the hint but getting the start and end time for that value looks a bit confusing

Comment: @Bha123 - I didn't say it wasn't clear, I asked what actually happened when you run the query. Please see the comment from Mohi which will help you phrase better questions. Better questions lead to quicker and better Answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know what you mean by confusing , for mysql

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T;
CREATE table T(
   Name      VARCHAR(26) NOT NULL 
  ,Timestamp VARCHAR(19)
  ,Value     INTEGER 
);
INSERT INTO T
(Name,Timestamp,Value) 
VALUES 
('M1','2022-05-04T00:00:00',580),
('M1','2022-05-04T00:01:00',581),
('M1','2022-05-04T00:02:00',582),
('M1','2022-05-04T00:03:00',583),
('M1','2022-05-04T00:04:00',584),
('M1','2022-05-04T00:05:00',584),
('M1','2022-05-04T00:06:00',584),
('M1','2022-05-04T00:07:00',584), 
('M1','2022-05-04T00:08:00',585),
('M1','2022-05-04T00:09:00',585), 
('M1','2022-05-04T00:10:00',586), 
('M1','2022-05-04T00:11:00',586),
('M1','2022-05-04T00:12:00',586),
('M1','2022-05-04T00:13:00',587),
('M1','2022-05-04T00:14:00',588);

SELECT NAME,MIN(TIMESTAMP) MINTS,MAX(TIMESTAMP) MAXTS,value
FROM T
GROUP BY NAME,VALUE HAVING TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,MINTS,MAXTS) > 1;




NAME, MINTS,                 MAXTS,                value
'M1', '2022-05-04T00:04:00', '2022-05-04T00:07:00', '584'
'M1', '2022-05-04T00:10:00', '2022-05-04T00:12:00', '586'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right lines using LAG but you also need to grab the previous timestamp and partition by the values e.g.

```
SELECT [name], startTime, endTime, [Value]
from
(
    SELECT [name],min([timestamp]) as startTime, max([timestamp]) as endTime,[value]
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT *, lag([Value]) OVER (partition by [Name],[value] ORDER by [value],[timestamp]) prevValue
                , lag([timestamp]) OVER (partition by [name],[value] ORDER by [value],[timestamp]) prevTime
        FROM table
    ) a
    GROUP BY [name],[value]
) b
WHERE Datediff(minute, starttime, endtime) > 1
```

It could probably do with some tidying up

Answer (score 0):

your data (In SQL Server)

```
Declare @a table(
   Name      VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL 
  ,Timestamp DATETIME
  ,Value     INTEGER 
);
INSERT INTO @a
(Name,Timestamp,Value) 
VALUES 
('M1','2022-05-04T00:00:00',580),
('M1','2022-05-04T00:01:00',581),
('M1','2022-05-04T00:02:00',582),
('M1','2022-05-04T00:03:00',583),
('M1','2022-05-04T00:04:00',584),
('M1','2022-05-04T00:05:00',584),
('M1','2022-05-04T00:06:00',584),
('M1','2022-05-04T00:07:00',584), 
('M1','2022-05-04T00:08:00',585),
('M1','2022-05-04T00:09:00',585), 
('M1','2022-05-04T00:10:00',586), 
('M1','2022-05-04T00:11:00',586),
('M1','2022-05-04T00:12:00',586),
('M1','2022-05-04T00:13:00',587),
('M1','2022-05-04T00:14:00',588);
```

to get your desired result, Use `Lag`, `Subquery`, and `Aggreagate function` as follows

```
SELECT Min(timestamp2) 'Start time',
       Max(timestamp)  'End time',
       value
FROM  (SELECT NAME,
              timestamp,
              value,
              Lag(a.timestamp)
                OVER (
                  partition BY a.NAME
                  ORDER BY timestamp)         Timestamp2,
              value - Lag(a.value)
                        OVER (
                          partition BY a.NAME
                          ORDER BY timestamp) flag
       FROM   @a a1) a2
WHERE  flag = 0
GROUP  BY value,
          flag
```

provided result

| Start time | End time | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-05-04T00:04:00 | 2022-05-04T00:07:00 | 584 |
| 2022-05-04T00:08:00 | 2022-05-04T00:09:00 | 585 |
| 2022-05-04T00:10:00 | 2022-05-04T00:12:00 | 586 |

Answer (score 0):

It could be easily done using `MIN()` and `MAX()`, grouped by Value (and the name column for completeness), with a `HAVING` clause to filter the grouped results:

```
--Using SQL Server, Your DDL
CREATE TABLE #temp (Name varchar(100), Timestamp varchar(100), Value int)
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES
('M1','2022-05-04T00:00:00', 580)
,('M1','2022-05-04T00:01:00', 581)
,('M1','2022-05-04T00:02:00', 582)
,('M1','2022-05-04T00:03:00', 583)
,('M1','2022-05-04T00:04:00', 584)
,('M1','2022-05-04T00:05:00', 584)
,('M1','2022-05-04T00:06:00', 584)
,('M1','2022-05-04T00:07:00', 584)
,('M1','2022-05-04T00:08:00', 585)
,('M1','2022-05-04T00:09:00', 585)
,('M1','2022-05-04T00:10:00', 586)
,('M1','2022-05-04T00:11:00', 586)
,('M1','2022-05-04T00:12:00', 586)
,('M1','2022-05-04T00:13:00', 587)
,('M1','2022-05-04T00:14:00', 588)

SELECT MIN(Timestamp) AS [Start time], Max(Timestamp) AS [End time]
      ,[Value]
  FROM #temp 
GROUP BY [Name], [Value]
HAVING DATEDIFF(MINUTE, MIN(Timestamp), MAX(Timestamp)) > 1
```

Creates identical output:

```
/*
Start time            End time              Value
2022-05-04T00:04:00   2022-05-04T00:07:00   584
2022-05-04T00:10:00   2022-05-04T00:12:00   586
*/
```